# How can I exclude a specific child category post from a parent category?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to display related post by category, but I wanted to exclude a specific category, but it's not working and I don't know how to tackle it.

```
<?php
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'category' );

    if ( empty( $terms ) ) {

        $terms = array();
    }

    $term_list = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'slug' );

    $related_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ),
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        'exclude' => 9,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $term_list
            )
        )
    );

    $my_query = new WP_Query($related_args);

    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : 

            $my_query->the_post();
            the_title();
            echo "<br>";

        endwhile;
    }
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use minus (-) sign with cat id that you want to exclude

```
$related_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ),
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'cat' => '-9'
);
```

Check this link:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Find: **Exclude Posts Belonging to Category**

[See Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vv9PP.png)

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you want to exclude category ID 9. then just add the follows tax query in your `$related_args` -

```
'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $term_list,
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array( 9 ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: This works even for where the post is in a child category of the category id